# Warning: The Command Line Tools for Xcode don't appear to be installed; most ports will likely fail to build

Tags: python, macos

I was trying to actually Install biopython on my new mac. Python 2.7 is already installed in it. To install biopython I found is good to install with macports. Now to install macports I need xcode but after running Xcode I installed macports which successfully installed. Then tried to install biopython using this command:
sudo port install py27-biopython
But ended up in a warning like this:
Warning: The Command Line Tools for Xcode don't appear to be installed; most ports will likely fail to build.

> Warning: See http://guide.macports.org/chunked/installing.xcode.html
>   for more information.
>   --->  Computing dependencies for py27-biopythonError: Unable to execute port: can't read "build.cmd": Failed to locate 'make' in path:
>   '/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin' or at
>   its MacPorts configuration time location, did you move it? To report a
>   bug, see http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets

What should I be doing as I am very new to mac os

Answer (score 30):

You can get Xcode from the Mac App Store as a free download. From within that (in the preferences | downloads) you can download and install the command line tools.

You might also need to tell the command line tools to use the versions within the Xcode app bundle rather than those in `/Developer` which aren't there with the new package based install.

Run this from the Terminal:

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

Comment: http://guide.macports.org/chunked/installing.xcode.html#installing.xcode.lion.43

Comment: i have xcode installed and stil get the error :( I was reading (http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.os.apple.macports.user/24058) and some people seem to think there are things missing due to installing it from the app store vs the old way of using the cd

Comment: @owengerig Have you installed the extra Command line tools from the Xcode Preferences menu? I've also updated my answer with a command you can run to tell your system where the command line tools are installed.

Comment: Sorry I missed that part about going to xcode> preferences >downloads>components, Thank you that fixed it

Answer (score 22):

Don't forget what I forgot:
After installing Xcode 4.3, the Command Line Tools must be installed. This is done from the Downloads section of Xcode's preferences!!!