# Installing Rails on Mavericks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, osx-mavericks

Not sure what happened but when I upgraded to Mavericks it says that Rails it not install. I executed the following command:

```
rails --version
```

And it said "Rails is not currently installed and run sudo gem install rails".

I run sudo gem install rails and get the following:

```
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h


Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/json-1.8.1 for inspection.
```

**UPDATE:**

I ran the command gcc --version and got the following:

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.76) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0
Thread model: posix
```

Comment: remember to mark the correct answer as accepted if it solved your problem

Answer (score 60):

You need to install the Command Line Developer Tools. Just open Terminal and type up a command that requires it -- for instance, `git`, `gcc` or `make`. Or use the following command:

```
$ xcode-select --install
```

You'll see an alert like this:

[image]

Just click Install and that's it. **As of OS X 10.9, there's no longer need to install Xcode** for Ruby development.

Credit for the steps and picture goes to Daniel Kehoe in his latest guide: http://railsapps.github.io/installrubyonrails-mac.html

Comment: It does not give me pop up! It seems like I already have command line tools installed.

Comment: Try this command (also from the linked guide): `xcode-select -p` and also make sure you do have gcc installed by doing a `gcc --version`.

Comment: Try `xcode-select --install` and report what you get, please.

Comment: Okay after running xcode-select --install the popup opened and then I installed the command line tools. They are now installed! What next?

Comment: If I run sudo gem install rails it throws the same old error.

Comment: It doesn't work always, I've been experiencing so many issues after installing Maverick and the only solution has been cleaning everything and reinstall nearly everything, not only xcode, also every single library with macports

Comment: This does not work anymore. It simply throws an errord "software not found on server"

Comment: Also make sure you have XCode installed and components set up. For me, all I had to do was open XCode, and click on Accept for terms & conditions screen, and then re-running the gem install worked for me.

Answer (score 15):

I had the same problem which I have now been able to solve.

The problem for me was that I had updated to the latest version of Xcode through the appstore but hadn't actually opened the application to complete the install. So here's what solved it for me:

- Updated Xcode
- Opened Xcode application
- Accepted license agreement
- Installed rails

Hope it works for you too.

Comment: This saved me! Thank you.
Ended up here after updating to Yosemite.  Ran my grunt build operation and a compass task failed with the following error:
"Warning: Couldn't find the `compass` binary. Make sure it's installed and in your $PATH"

Comment: ...
Turns out that both Compass and Ruby must be installed correctly for grunt use.  
I went through https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-compass/issues/66 to realise that Ruby and Compass versions needed to be updated and the gem install for compass was failing due to the path pointing to the incorrect version of Ruby.  The reason for this is now clear due to this answer.  Hope this saves time for someone else

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't working for me even when I reinstalled xcode and the command line tools for mavericks.

But after that, I just did a `bundle update` and, for some reason, it worked.

Comment: sorry, bundle isn't in my path. Could you let me know where the executable is?

Comment: @CamdenNarzt `bundle` is a ruby gem. You need to run `gem install bundler` (maybe with sudo) to install it.

Answer (score 0):

I think I had the same issues. I updated the xcode and open xcode to accept licence aggrement. Then it worked fine as far as I can remember.

Comment: Also 'sudo gcc' worked.  It gave me a cli way to accept the license.