# Error installing cf-uaac on OSX El Capitan

Tags: ruby, macos, cloudfoundry-uaa, cloud-foundry

Trying to install the cf-uaac gem on OS X El Capitan.

`$ gem install cf-uaac`

Result:

```
Fetching: cf-uaa-lib-3.2.5.gem (100%)
Successfully installed cf-uaa-lib-3.2.5
Fetching: highline-1.6.21.gem (100%)
Successfully installed highline-1.6.21
ERROR: Error installing cf-uaac:
       ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
     /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb

mkmf.rb can’t find header files for ruby at /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3 for inspection.

Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/extensions/universal-darwin-15/2.0.0/eventmachine-1.0.3/gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a little research it appears El Capitan has made several changes related to Ruby. Some suggestions for a fix centered around rebooting and making some dangerous changes to the system.

Below is how I got it to work.

**Installed rbenv**

`brew install rbenv ruby-build`

**Add rbenv to the `.bash_profile`**

`echo 'if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi' >> ~/.bash_profile`

**Source the `~/.bash_profile`**

`source ~/.bash_profile`

**Install Ruby with rbenv**

`rbenv install 2.2.3`

**Set this version globally**

`rbenv global 2.2.3`

**Check your Ruby version**

`ruby -v`

**Install cf-uaac**

`gem install cf-uaac`

Anyone with a better solution please let me know.

Comment: Might be hard to debug because you can't easily go back to your old setup.  But was `gem install eventmachine -v 1.0.3` failing?

Comment: I did not try that.  I think the issue is El Capitan and the way they changed how Ruby works.  I did try some random gems Rails etc...  All Failed.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was resolved for me after I installed Xcode.

Following is the command to install xcode:

```
$ xcode-select --install

$ gem install cf-uaac
```

Reference 
[Installing Rails on Mavericks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19580685/installing-rails-on-mavericks)