# Can't brew install postgresql on Mac Snow Leopard

Tags: macos, postgresql, osx-snow-leopard, homebrew

Trying to install PostgreSQL on my OSX 10.6.8:

```
$ brew install postgresql
```

**Output (Try 1):**

```
==> Installing dependencies for postgresql: ossp-uuid
==> Installing postgresql dependency: ossp-uuid
==> Downloading ftp://ftp.ossp.org/pkg/lib/uuid/uuid-1.6.2.tar.gz

curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
Trying a mirror...
==> Downloading http://gnome-build-stage-1.googlecode.com/files/uuid-1.6.2.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ossp-uuid/1.6.2 --without-perl --without-php --without-pgsql
==> make
make: *** [uuid_sha1.lo] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make: *** [uuid_md5.lo] Error 1
make: *** [uuid.lo] Error 1
make: *** [uuid_prng.lo] Error 1

READ THIS: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/troubleshooting
```

**Output (Try 2):**

```
==> Installing dependencies for postgresql: ossp-uuid
==> Installing postgresql dependency: ossp-uuid
==> Downloading ftp://ftp.ossp.org/pkg/lib/uuid/uuid-1.6.2.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/ossp-uuid-1.6.2.tar.gz
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ossp-uuid/1.6.2 --without-perl --without-php --without-pgsql
==> make
i686-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1: vfork: Operation timed out
gcc-4.2: vfork: Operation timed out
make: *** [uuid_prng.lo] Error 1
make: *** [uuid_md5.lo] Error 1
make: *** [uuid.lo] Error 1

READ THIS: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/troubleshooting
```

No idea what to do with this. The [READ THIS link](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/troubleshooting) is useless. Anybody?

---

**UPDATE:** Tried brew doctor, which didn't give me anything useful AFAIK, just some warnings about where it was looking for Python:

```
Warning: "config" scripts exist outside your system or Homebrew directories.
`./configure` scripts often look for *-config scripts to determine if
software packages are installed, and what additional flags to use when
compiling and linking.

Having additional scripts in your path can confuse software installed via
Homebrew if the config script overrides a system or Homebrew provided
script of the same name. We found the following "config" scripts:

    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python-config
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7-config
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

error message is not related to postgresql. Have you tried `brew doctor`? 
try `brew doctor` and see this link ([OS X 10.8 - error trying to exec '/usr/bin/i686-apple-darwin11-gcc-4.2.1' - installing json gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710568/os-x-10-8-error-trying-to-exec-usr-bin-i686-apple-darwin11-gcc-4-2-1-inst)) I think you should focus on `vfork operation timed out` message

Comment: yea i had tried brew doctor, but none of the warnings seemed relevant. The vfork operation timed out message doesn't appear every time, but Ill look into it more...

Comment: Just tried it with the `--without-ossp-uuid` flag, but still failing. Not ready to re-install homebrew, etc, I'll submit a [**ticket**](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/22804) first. Thanks for trying.

Comment: @appleparan- Turns out it probably was just a simple resource limit issue, see the resolution of the ticket- so you were right about the vfork operation - thanks for your help